# Flink - Test Sink that can be used with .sinkTo

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using a `KafkaSink` to sink the results to kafka like `.sinkTo(kafkaSink)`. I'm trying to come up with an end to end integration test and want to use a simple sink for the same. I came across `CollectSink` where I can add results to a list and do the matchers. But, CollectSink being `SinkFunction`, I am not able to use it in `.sinkTo`, instead `addSink` is where it can be used.

I have tried `PrintSink` but I want to read the saved data again to do some matchers.

Can anyone help me on how I can add a test sink so that it can be used along with `.sinkTo`?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could look at how the integration tests for the Immerok Cookbook are organized. https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/creating-dead-letter-queues-from-and-to-apache-kafka-with-apache-flink/ might be good place to start, since it illustrates how to approach testing a job with multiple sinks.

Disclaimer: I work for Immerok

Comment: Thanks @Martijn for your response. I'll check that.

Comment: @Martijin, If I use PrintSink, is there a way I can get back the values from PrintSink. I found printSink to be simple and want to make use of that.